# How to pass a @liaoliaots/nestjs-redis redis connection to global guard constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, nestjs

i'm new in NestJS and have some misunderstands with @liaoliaots/nestjs-redis(https://github.com/liaoliaots/nestjs-redis) package. For example, i have a guard with following constructor:

```
import { InjectRedis } from '@liaoliaots/nestjs-redis';
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';

@Injectable()
export class SomeGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(@InjectRedis() redis: Redis) {}
    
    ...
}
```

and then i want that guard to be global:

```
//main.ts
...
app.useGlobalGuards(new SomeGuard(/* what??? */));
...
```

so thats a problem: what i need to pass? `@InjectRedis` makes weird things:)

thx for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `app.useGlobalGuards`, use this another way:

```
// ...
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core'

@Module({
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: SomeGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

is cleaner and helps you avoid polluting your boostrap funcion. Also, it lets Nest resolves that `Redis` dependency. Otherwise you'll need to get this dependency and pass it to `new SomeGuard` using
`const redis = app.get(getRedisToken())`

- https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards